# Python with Itertools?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a `.csv` the contains 3 columns. PersonX, PersonY, and PersonZ. There are 7000 rows of names and different combinations. My goal is to see what pair and group of 3 are the highest match. I have not been able to find a formula in excel that would achieve this goal. I'm sure python would be able to with itertools combination but I'm not that advanced yet. The names can be in any order, just looking to see how many times those 2 or 3 people are in the same row. Any suggestions would be a great help, thank you!

**Small Example of Data**.

```
PersonX         PersonY             PersonZ
Aaron Ekblad    Keith Yandle        Vincent Trocheck
Aaron Ekblad    Denis Malgin        Mike Matheson
Aaron Ekblad    Denis Malgin        Mike Matheson
Aaron Ekblad    Jonathan Huberdeau  Keith Yandle
Aaron Ekblad    Jonathan Huberdeau  Keith Yandle
Aaron Ekblad    Jamie McGinn        Keith Yandle
Aaron Ekblad    Aleksander Barkov   Jonathan Huberdeau
Aaron Ekblad        
Adam Erne       Andrej Sustr        Vladislav Namestnikov
Adam Erne       Anthony Cirelli 
Adam Erne       
Adam Henrique   Rickard Rakell      Ryan Getzlaf
Adam Henrique   Brandon Montour     Ryan Getzlaf
Adam Henrique   Corey Perry         Brandon Montour
Adam Henrique   Corey Perry         Brandon Montour
Adam Henrique   Brian Gibbons       Andy Greene
Adam Henrique   Ryan Getzlaf    
Adam Henrique   Ondrej Kase 
Adam Henrique   Josh Manson 
Adam Henrique   Brian Gibbons   
Adam Henrique       
Adam Henrique
```

**Starting Script**

```
import csv
from itertools import combinations, product

#Header = PersonX PersonY PersonZ

#Import Game
with open('1718_All_Goals_&_Assists.csv', newline='') as f:
    next(f)
    skaters = '\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in csv.reader(f))
    print(skaters)
```

Comment: What would be the result for your dataset (and why)? Also what's the delimiter in your dataset? It cannot be whitespace because the names contain whitespaces and your sample doesn't contain tabs.

Comment: a number of times a pair or group has been together. Than i can order by largest and see the most frequent pair or group

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply use `collections.Counter` on your `csv.reader`:

```
from collections import Counter

>>> cnt = Counter(frozenset(item.strip() for item in line if item.strip()) for line in csv.reader(f))
```

You can get the sorted (descending) output by using the `.most_common` method of Counter:

```
>>> cnt.most_common()
[(frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Denis Malgin', 'Mike Matheson'}), 2),
 (frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Jonathan Huberdeau', 'Keith Yandle'}), 2),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Brandon Montour', 'Corey Perry'}), 2),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique'}), 2),
 (frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Keith Yandle', 'Vincent Trocheck'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Jamie McGinn', 'Keith Yandle'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Aleksander Barkov', 'Jonathan Huberdeau'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Erne', 'Andrej Sustr', 'Vladislav Namestnikov'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Erne', 'Anthony Cirelli'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Erne'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Rickard Rakell', 'Ryan Getzlaf'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Brandon Montour', 'Ryan Getzlaf'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Andy Greene', 'Brian Gibbons'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Ryan Getzlaf'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Ondrej Kase'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Josh Manson'}), 1),
 (frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Brian Gibbons'}), 1)]
```

Similarly you can get the most common (in case of ties it will return just one of those) using this:

```
>>> cnt.most_common(1)
[(frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Denis Malgin', 'Mike Matheson'}), 2)]
```

If you want all that have the maximum count you could use a custom approach using `max`:

```
>>> maximum_occurences = max(cnt.values())
>>> [group for group, occurences in cnt.items() if occurences == maximum_occurences]
[frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Denis Malgin', 'Mike Matheson'}),
 frozenset({'Aaron Ekblad', 'Jonathan Huberdeau', 'Keith Yandle'}),
 frozenset({'Adam Henrique', 'Brandon Montour', 'Corey Perry'}),
 frozenset({'Adam Henrique'})]
```

#### To add a bit more explanation:

`Counter` just counts elements, which should be exactly what you want - but the values to count have to be hashable. That's inconvenient because `csv.reader` will return lists (inconvenient because lists are unhashable), so you need another data-structure.

`tuples` will come to mind, however because you said that the names could be in any order you probably want an unordered collection. That means you should use `frozenset`. There is one caveat though: It cannot hold the same value multiple times, so if you have people with the same name you cannot use that.

I don't know how your csv is structured, so it's likely that the result may contain empty "columns" or whitespace before/after the names, that's why I filtered empty elements and stripped the names with:

```
item.strip() for item in line if item.strip()
```

before passing it to the `frozenset`.

In case you don't like that it `strips` twice you could add another comprehension or `map`:

```
frozenset(item for item in (item.strip() for item in line) if item)
frozenset(item for item in map(lambda x: x.strip(), line) if item)
frozenset(item for item in map(str.strip, line) if item)  # if all items are really of type str
```

By the way the outer comprehension could then be replaced by `filter` by `bool`:

```
frozenset(filter(bool, map(str.strip, line)))
```

Oh, the wonders of "functional programming". And I haven't even used `itertools`.

I totally forgot: In case you want to omit the single-person-groups you could easily filter the `Counter` before you access the `most_common` groups:

```
cnt = Counter({k: v for k, v in cnt.items() if len(k) > 1})
```

That can be applied afterwards or you can try to fiddle that into the comprehension inside the `Counter`, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the interested reader.

---

Just in case you could have the same name multiple times in one line and you don't want to lose that "information" you could count the names in each line and then convert that Counter to a tuple that is going to be counted.

```
Counter(tuple(Counter(filter(bool, map(str.strip, line))).most_common()) for line in csv.reader(f))
```

I hope I haven't overdone it with the one-liners.

Comment: Wow, thanks Mseifert! Would it be possible to edit my script above for this to work? Having some trouble writing it out. Also, is it possible to export these results in a csv as well? I will mark this answered but i am just having an issue writing it out.

Comment: Is there a way to do the most common pair?

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson What would be the most common pair in this case and how should the resulting csv look like? With regards to the script: Replace the `skaters = '\n'.join(' '.join(row) for row in csv.reader(f))` and the `print(skaters)` with the lines from my answer you want to use, for example with `cnt = Counter(frozenset(item.strip() for item in line if item.strip()) for line in csv.reader(f))` and `print(cnt.most_common(1))`.

Comment: I was able to get it working last night thank you. I was hoping there is a way to see the most common pairs. for example, if john, frank, joe are in one line and joe, john, tom are in a row, the most common pair would be joe and john 2 times. If you could export out the csv, it would be nice to see most_common_pair(20) and the number of times they were together. is that possible?